# How to make a workflow to stop and check a field's value and based on the value of the field proceed using SharePoint 2010 Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

i am badly stuck in one point and i am not finding any good alternative logic for it, let me explain it:

I have created a custom List WF using SP 2010 Designer.

The user submits a form request, including a date, that is routed to the handler and is either approved or rejected.

If the request is approved, then the workflow should pause until either:

1. the requester makes a change to the form (and it goes back for re-approval).
2. or the user won't do any changes and the WorkFlow should continue after checking whether the user brought changes or didn't

I used pause for a duration but the time after approval is not clear how long it should wait  to check whether the user brought changes or no? please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Check if Date Created + 2 weeks (or whatever duration is when the WF should continue whether any changes have been made) <= (less than or equal to) Today's date, if yes, continue workflow, if not:
Compare date modified and date created to check if the item was modified after it's been added, if yes, reroute for approval.